# Saving the stdout of gitpython calls?

Tags: python, django, git, gitpython

```
directory = repo.directory
r = git.Repo(directory)

if r:
    r.git.reset('--hard')
    if r.remotes[repo.remote]:
        r.remotes[repo.remote].pull()
```

I want to save the stdout of any operation on my `r` object, including any `.reset` or `.pull` calls - how can I go about doing this?